# ImageMagick not converting

Tags: imagemagick, osx-snow-leopard

I've just installed a fresh copy of ImageMagick from source onto Snow Leopard 1.6.8 following [these instructions](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) minus the `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib` command because that doesn't seem to exist on Mac.

Then I added this to my global bash file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/imagemagick/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Now when I run `which identify` I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/identify
```

And when I run the tests, GIF files remain GIF files:

```
Simpleton:Desktop pawel$ convert logo.gif logo.png
Simpleton:Desktop pawel$ file logo.png 
logo.png: GIF image data, version 89a, 640 x 480
```

And when I want to convert a JPG file I get:

```
Simpleton:Desktop pawel$ convert clouds.jpg clouds.png
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `clouds.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: missing an image filename `clouds.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3016.
```

When I run `identify -list format` then I can't see PNG or JPEG libraries. How do I add these without reinstalling ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run `identify -list format` I can see that the PNG and JPG delegate libraries are missing. I installed `jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz` from http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/ and installed it using [these instructions](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2008/11/fix-for-convert-no-decode-delegate-for-this-image-format/) and reinstalled ImageMagick. I can now convert to JPG and still not to PNG so I'll obviously have to add that library.