# Missing image filename ImageMagick convert running from Node.js only

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I built a little script that will first montage 8 tiles together, then scale it down and then it has to distort the image.

Everything goes according to plan until the distorting part.

```
this.distort = function(filename) {
  var distortDeferred = Q.defer();

  var totalWidth = width * waves * 2,
      totalHeight = height * waves * 2;

  var params = [
    filename,
    '-matte',
    '-virtual-pixel',
    'transparent',
    '-distort',
    'Perspective "{left},{top} {newLeft},{top}   {left},{bottom} {left},{bottom}   {right},{bottom} {right},{bottom}    {right},{top} {newRight},{top}"'.assign({
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      newLeft: totalWidth * distortPercentage,
      bottom: totalHeight,
      right: totalWidth,
      newRight: totalWidth - totalWidth * distortPercentage
    }),
    filename
  ];

  im.convert(params, function() {
    console.log(arguments);
  });

  return distortDeferred.promise;
};
```

This following function wil give the error:

```
Error: Command failed: convert: missing an image filename `tmp/5458f2e3d6840bb65ba6100f.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3184.
```

Running the exact same operation on the command line, will have the desired output.

Possible mistakes I could have made and that I have tested:

- Two image converts, converting the image at the same time
- Non existing image
- File rights to the image are not set correctly
- Missing plugins for ImageMagick

**Two image converts, converting the image at the same time**

Everything is done with deferreds and promises, so it's not possible that two requests run at the same time, to be sure I set a 2000ms timeout before the distort function was called. Also no help.

**Non existing image**

Tested this to be sure with a `fs.fileExists`. Result was as expected.

**File rights to the image are not set correctly**

To be safe I tried a `chmod -R 777 folder` on the folder. Result was as expected.

**Missing plugins for ImageMagick**

After some googling I came across some people that didn't have the appropriate plugins installed and received the same error as me.

Apparently it had something to with either a JPEG library missing or a PNG, [see error here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488695/imagemagick-not-converting).

So after running `identify -list format`, it was apparent that I have the appropriate libraries installed to complete an operation like this.

**Synopsis**

I think the error is also probably found in node instead of ImageMagick, because the operation runs from the command line without a problem.